# Adding hreflang tags automatically in WordPress subdirectory multisite

Tags: php, multisite

We have a WordPress MU subdirectory network setup:

- [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) - main website, USA, global
- [www.example.com/uk/](http://www.example.com/uk/) - to display for UK visitors
- [www.example.com/au/](http://www.example.com/au/) - to display for Australian visitors.

We want to add `hreflang` tags for each webpage and exclude the `locations` custom post type.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70581915/adding-hreflang-tags-automatically-in-wordpress-multisite), I've adjusted the code in the child theme's
`functions.php` to:

```
function add_hreflang_attribute() {
   $site_url = network_site_url(); // base URL
   $alt_langs = array( 'au', 'uk' ); // two-letter language code
   $page_path = substr(get_permalink(), strlen(home_url('/'))); // path of page after base URL
   
   if (!( is_singular( 'locations' ) ) ) {
           
       // loop through the alternative languages, and get the appropriate hreflang tag for each that exists
       foreach ($alt_langs as $lang) {
           $updated_url_lang_path = $site_url . $lang . '/' . $page_path;
           $url_headers = @get_headers($updated_url_lang_path);
           if($url_headers && strpos( $url_headers[0], '200')) {
               if ($lang == 'uk') {
                   echo '<link rel="alternate" href="' . $updated_url_lang_path . '" hreflang="en-gb" />'. PHP_EOL;
               } elseif ($lang == '') {
                 
               }
               else {
                   echo '<link rel="alternate" href="' . $updated_url_lang_path . '" hreflang="en-' . $lang . '" />'. PHP_EOL;
               }
           }
       }
       
       // set primary as x-default
       echo '<link rel="alternate" href="' . $site_url . $page_path . '" hreflang="x-default" />';
        
   }

}
```

This code works on the main website's home page & example page: `www.example.com/features/`;

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/au/features/" hreflang="en-au" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/uk/features/" hreflang="en-gb" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/features/" hreflang="x-default" />
```

and it works for the:

- AU site's home page,
- the AU site's features page: `https://www.example.com/au/features/`,

but on `www.example.com/uk/` it only produces:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/au/" hreflang="en-au" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/" hreflang="x-default" />
```

It is missing:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/uk/" hreflang="en-gb" />
```

The features page is a simple WordPress page.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively we can set the `hreflang` as a **site** **meta** for each site:

```
update_site_meta( 1, 'hreflang', 'x-default' );
update_site_meta( 3, 'hreflang', 'en-au' );
update_site_meta( 5, 'hreflang', 'en-gb' );
```

and then for the `hreflang` attribute use;

```
get_site_meta( $site->blog_id, 'hreflang' )
```

and for the `href` attribute:

```
get_home_url( $site->blog_id, $page_path )
```

If we want to skip the site meta and use:

```
$hreflangs = array(
    1 => 'x-default',
    3 => 'en-au',
    5 => 'en-gb',
);
```

then the sites loop becomes:

```
$page_path = substr( get_permalink(), strlen( home_url('/') )); 

$sites = get_sites();
foreach ( $sites as $site ) {
    if ( isset( $hreflangs[ $site->blog_id ] ) ) {
        printf ( 
            '<link rel="alternate" href="%s" hreflang="%s" />'. PHP_EOL,
            esc_url( get_home_url( $site->blog_id, $page_path ) ),
            esc_attr( $hreflangs[ $site->blog_id ] )
        );
    }
}
```

One might further check if the page-path/slug exists on each site with e.g. `get_page_by_path()` or `get_posts()` via `switch_to_blog()`.

Comment: I've added an `EDIT2` to my question as an attempt to wrap your answer in functions.

Comment: we only need to run the update on site meta once and we should remember escaping the outputs with esc_url and esc_attr (Im just writing from a phone.  :-)

Comment: if you want to skip site meta you can define an array relating blog id to hreflang.

Comment: I can only award the bounty 24 hours after I created it. I will award it to you tomorrow.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped @Steve

Comment: ahh think we need to change the get_permalink()
part :-) Will look into that

Comment: Hopefully the href attributes are correct now